# How to set the correct answer via checkbox?

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have this program (is PHP):

```
<div id="count2">
        <label>Question 1</label>
        <input type="text" name="pregunta1" class="form-control" style="width:300px;" placeholder="Pregunta 1">
        <br>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3" id="count">
                <label>Reply 1</label>
              <input type="text" name="respuesta1_1" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Respuesta 1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" id="count">
            <label>Correct?</label>
              <input type="radio" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" name="correcta1" value="yes">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" id="count">
                <label>Help 1</label>
              <input type="text" name="ayuda1_1" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Ayuda 1">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3" id="count">
                <label>Reply 2</label>
              <input type="text" name="respuesta2_1" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Respuesta 2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" id="count">
            <label>Correct?</label>
              <input type="radio" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" name="correcta1" value="yes">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" id="count">
                <label>Help 2</label>
              <input type="text" name="ayuda2_1" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Ayuda 2">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I can set dinamically questions and answers, is a kind of exam that you can, for example, add one more question, and inside this question, one more answer/correct?/help

After this, i insert this via MYSQL:

```
$numQuestions = $_GET['p'];
$numResponses = $_GET['r'];

$title= $_POST['titulo'];
$resumen = $_POST['resumen'];
$fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$insertExame = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO examenes(title,resumen,fecha,private,users_idUsers) VALUES('$title','$resumen','$fecha','no','$_SESSION[user]')");


    $numExam = $mysqli->insert_id;
    $question= array();
    $correct = array();
    $reply = array();
    $help = array();

    for ($i=1; $i <= $numQuestions; $i++) {
        $question[$i] = $_POST['question'.$i];
        $insertQuestion = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO questions(question,privado,exam_idExam,user_idUser) VALUES('$question[$i]','no','$numExame','$_SESSION[user]')");

        $idQuestion = $mysqli->insert_id;

    for ($k=1; $k <= $numResponses; $k++) {
    $reply[$k] = $_POST['reply'.$k.'_'.$i];
    $help[$k] = $_POST['help'.$k.'_'.$i];
    $correct[$i] = $_POST['correct'.$i];

    if($reply[$k] != "" || $reply[$k] != null) {
    $insertaResponse = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO replies(reply,help,correct,private,exam_idExam,question_idQuestion,user_idUser) VALUES('$reply[$k]','$help[$k]','$correct[$i]','no','$numExam','$idQuestion','$_SESSION[user]')");
    }
}
```

The program is in spanish so some words my be not translated, sorry.

The database is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `examns` (
`idExam` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(85) NOT NULL,
  `resumen` text NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `private` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `user_idUser` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions` (
`idQuestion` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `question` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `private` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `exam_idExam` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_idUser` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=42 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `replies` (
`idReply` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reply` text NOT NULL,
  `help` text NOT NULL,
  `correct` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `private` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `exam_idExam` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `question_idQuestion` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_idUser` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want to do this: I want to set to the table replies, the correct answer when it is. For example, if I have:

Question 1: What is your fauvorite colour?

Reply 1: Red Correct?: Yes(Checked) Help 1: ""

Reply 2: Blue Correct? No(No Checked) Help 2: Is not blue because...

And not I want to the insert to mysql make two new inserts, the first that checkbox have "yes", and the second one that have "no".

I hope you understand this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to collect all checkboxes values in several variables, then you can insert all these records with a single insert query using the following syntax :

```
INSERT INTO example
  (example_id, name, value, other_value)
VALUES
  (1, 'Name 1', '$var1', 'Other 1'),
  (2, 'Name 2', '$var2', 'Other 2'),
  (3, 'Name 3', '$var3', 'Other 3'),
  (4, 'Name 4', '$var4', 'Other 4');
```

Comment: Maybe but then you'll need to explain your problem better because what I understood is that you want to insert multiple records with a single `INSERT` statement, and this syntax does exactly that. Now if you don't know how to write this query or get an error while executing it, that's another issue...